# Generating public and private keys in Java generates similar starts of all keys, both private and public

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am using Java to generate two public / private keys. Over and over again. Each time different. But they always start the same. The hash o generate them differs.

I've come to understand that this is the algorithm being encoded to the start. However, I think I'd prefer if third parties had as little info as possible, including what is being used to generate them.

In `sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.writeReplace()` method I can see the algorithm being included.

1. I understand that his part of the public / private key is readable. I would like to know what it is. How do I make it visible what is says? Base64 decoding the start yields nothing readable.
2. How can I remove this info from the header? And what are the consequences? It is really only to be used internally so we can hardcode the missing pieces if necessary.
3. Any other ideas on why this information is included by default and so hard to code away? RsaPublicKey is final. We should be able to get the public key and private key in their mathematical form if we required to. **Prime number and exponent**. Why is all this crap included?

I prefer if nothing about our system is revealed, including Java, Jetty, RSA, AES, DES or what not.

But first and foremost, **what** **are** **these** **parts**?

### Printing public keys:

**MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA**opcFuEA6sraQ/U7ae77DBd9rFYDC5LhTn6B4hy/vecRB1Wyb44/HZxI4pUJgUZ+eUNtDucbxhc9vl9wC77MRJoyKV59M4sMjVMX3omhqvFcvKysktGhseRJsrfS/NIbL3JHDk1PC37c8m2xglnCvS8tK7nD8p4hVygj2jRCiHcLMasZ0m2ZB44t0Fc4zRp/Z5Gkj72tgke5iLmxoPjAJu+DS9/EUAck1jsEKWaDLFR7AWPKiMPysqIiiJi3Gy5ukOWhvb+T5dvFSCWKvFG9ftmyFPC4hqmjJGG8GsD4imA2HCSvpM+iLLJWYtZ7jzNQCNtIsU2kEogt4K5FGgQ/e0DOld0ynRirDtBJsgYD2s68vv0kl8zrNt8l9IEFnI4PhmjfKtj1oL35T/Mdi7PxGG/pyoTiUXjXr5ASIk8Z6i+yp2A787nhKF5RW2x0WOb8TSu3l6iBMbQOqt8Z81gHiqGaIWYUqU911Yu/znNQFj1PwVb+bzVm5lOGHHfHFJeT2ULHKZYEK5tIYDL1+JFeEKVPJMpjJzgMOnseaV5kXMHFWkvCmyObFX7f63JeV+OHTtoZrzYp6Ky9Zkth6FV3AcPJcyHjcbeoMck75V0JI1M0FK7QFwN+t3r8tfmCCjHUu9XExigJELOByR+8O6643il7dyciLg8v4ZU7bbJDeeSMCAwEAAQ==

**MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEA**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

### Printing private keys:

**MIIJRAIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCS**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

**MIIJQgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCS**wwggkoAgEAAoICAQCGkpQ00FvnCv6l/j75rwR7997qxabwdmYJJx0FTZdaWocUd1ihurePirrWhBjMUTFVe/srHRxNoswkSdOtrH61lKdMHOuApxvjijhMgdWjNp4D0CA5uQwPS1VzfUXzNoZ73nmve2Ic25Dia0OOLtjspnxj2se9uOjKh4h2eiZyqmYNHPueWbOrBVDycKDjsodLEkYsYUILQrOuazgvja31jnmMPHrF2FyZVGyhrHfIud+gDZ8vTw2QJJKMb+RY93dVxDgEEoBkkFUomCghHJwWFQOIww0LiSsAOv+vhBKyVpFyj/4F26KWQumAWIgqaJpZdlPDXJJi2GowQxUS4wH5R1+i4fprwVo/NViGL2lJEX10udBvy3Ch4S8bdG37Mw9ugCJbwEqOJJEH5jxQ3gJrYU9E4GV9WjzzDVv1/6yDrYIQXadwdBQrEVNQJem8Lk/cNRhwEaxh2qzQ9S58sXMtuwW36cjDcbWU7Ekmn14AbyMjbgPlytXtlX60eRFL0VQbI0Z+xs2QuBow4alNZXZET4Ut+d8EoyJqMsoCk1xMr9k6gaJkiNMxH3cq3Gi5Kfb+8Ts9mPx6UsB6LBM/+ps6YkXuNzNESit4CNNl/fmHJVBtFT5bdpPtYp35v1DmKyfAomQ7J1FhG/yhw4nttI/XvCjW9JP5rayenQ7p5FtwUwIDAQABAoICAHmYXoQuNKxaWegBCEQxqTqeqPS3rXUfdmkUx3swNe81V1Ld198iyJPSBaqpZ4LOZmZYhYXaYuWfkRfFAZivATrvXA9BHmZ8GI4MKXyv4Cr+wd6uI0Ak/Umgh1C4RAlUHkY0qv0t3mQ23P5Jb5w8plOGx2SuncbHGslNl7d9/dmkMFvu8UiOwvJn9lFqBWZYvTjPBUs6giOMnLCgPv9w5Fu55ggZ6dF1A46kIxger4lWskJ7rHdh1d6FvUlaHRlqWZDMoNTFJvA3Hkt02OW6ZSrqx+u+Wr4urgUiSj/8daxg3kGG7D+8ync9dKE83aR8KeNmMJ+YuMjJxYFgS91p8zBBB8O6hKIqE3/muN0fC4TSgUWrF3vtVvkQJioPsJfKLO/8AMcfXu5A5jpojwY2ix4FG+Qfh76Hu7m1WlBumMNyqEzDhf0WpqwQQ0ZnTBxvxob1XeFicCZAec+X5m2+h2GZFoPrlhr3FRv1HeYOc4TxkCyd7365lK7gjXvdzDpLPzYFhblQXbIJXI3hSA0EptNWll+4bEKheEmXrQ5WcGpLUStBNInDOuo+GFgGhDRZ0Z38jc0axIGqm+9U7A2SYkdadnZ9TqkDbY9dUSxnwUN/j/GBGX4QuUuf/QPCPdod7bIo6H+PMII2Zggv3k4VqfIgwVjREIlTYDe5C2O0nYrhAoIBAQDxWlfsP5zMHXbeBT83EH60MMxZ1ZvvmWTs/LnSW5jWPHY7s1Z+JMna1AqCL8PocUAukUZGekUbdn0t0rlzVKcaBHLRaZuuY3A6geYwmw4CqK0gIPLOQ8OBAHUmBaHB7Bctz4rLIdkF6VePL6OCa9kxyhw083q1/mCd2TIQKdoH8+4qxiKOz+TfNe57ajGy5Ipqh2pJwLXGze3p+ywR/V+8wabb+Tuj6nig5T5KpjY14B9ifiVPqNI3RZj92xfvFp0O386Cukuhd0HsB0YTP1bJQnm/wnbmgHnfEGaZGSte0zqYiLO420Ivcbw6H4AwFrW0dZ5OlLAyzhSnpx6DnbpxAoIBAQCOvUwXX+z2HuxTU9TNXS3SObewpdpchsMdrQE1FYVNgRgf1v156AscCW79SHyg5ecuorgdqlR5DtTNrWVNY77e02jVOZH8idCO/0dn2pXJ8EaCV2kz7Objj+LyGlyIgPY0S0FswLI5eg/iRL4DeMkMRqQwcp92wPTMU+IrTvKEcAgVPybMSRt6Rirh7iKzxHUjbkjGYv0XOUaWacOg7i0pVyh+WhUBMkag8dOsYEQGzdpY9vlJl5irSxwb7lnCMMc0YJT05PyKbmYYTI08KaMLB4R6F4KXl56Mh4CAsnpNlAQt23miMO2ZF9FlXiRNR74bjc+pG7oWhzduCUjHDNEDAoIBAQCMG7MgzYjboVso5gjdkXDMb+uhVvTQMc86GDhTWqMt8yl73M8gKYEYzLFRBCOJY30ry1/td/t4Rt/CYysPPZxH6T8yPEmJAebbwB7+JnUKrBrcpOPvQ71RvQ9ExE40Ajcue+YJqBuRZ/VRhQk5pBwQ4FBhmNqqngI+gCCk63bL2RpwsFbNavhlb6yC7pHtVOjZkMTuDbY4s8EibJIX22vhatXPqy6pKGtgk9QGh9i+i94MUkicptdqCLgY3kBVpl4EjX4Xu8g98rpNJ6fRcpqR+UouPNjDVN/q012MEOVxhdPlSq5yaK5SVoc7gp/qyrQvD3yYB48F30Z0UPrQ0xaxAoIBAGQUyAhPovcCwZK/YaLIZXtUKr5523wqpR3mksUknL21+TNB66IRF9EFsEN5EqFB8XFaeBuctPPYeU7o9/FmMYtM0eFHJ1vZSVkqFmfz9DiN9vIm1cWpok4GMgqsfxrayUXrSik1hwET25U7u7r1conf8fliNPrv2fR2EEtrZFGFt7Ul/U8ZJ2H5VtHoxX4kDjnUdsRa3bft2ddWuurYdOPaj7Lf+IBJPwpT5KWlLa1TonfkWu/Fki7wT/opidfFmbbYzThUYdmyBHWfHxwC2aW/FJ0CZPdjQLCpxWj3Oxev46o/i64z/jPsZk5bzro8xkfNi7+3iCeJkUzex5+BFf8CggEASv2oLIyZYqRIxYh91mZVk0HNFeWTa9LbrxW8w0foQVY3eabmccLOuLV/7/pHzqxBu7dL2UF83sjDXJK7+U8bQjr8r3Tq40NQCqamgxVQ4/QHmeOw5ww9s2FYrLG7gekf4QuML1vsSIsVYsfcZKDAiAzoQldd06dcqUeJ6aO6Y9OVDxOoIDbnTDRhMHK+US3AbG8n/ZzInbyq8DjwPcv6pwkZ2L5ma6fLBB/IyI6XfChkIeFedys9Y7K/vkfCKrPYW2mLbr1s/A5fOPgw8OiE/e83biMhO1NLJDQ1r4gdMEeZXiJrTE16tJLUaIMDofrPlRPTlLijFwZ6piduDETH4g==

Comment: `base64 -D <<<'YOUR_KEY_HERE' | openssl asn1parse -i -inform DER`

Comment: Keys can be specified in various formats, e.g. the posted public keys are specified in X.509/SPKI format and the posted private keys are specified in PKCS#8 format. Both formats use ASN.1 as description language, so that the data can be read with an ASN.1 parser, e.g. https://lapo.it/asn1js/. It can be seen that the identical segments correspond to identical structures or information such as the OID within the container.

Comment: Key formats are chosen for security *and* interoperability/portability. There are no **significant** security weakness introduced by the **extra** information that's included to enhance portability. There are so few common PK algorithms that even without that information an attacker could quickly try all possibilities to find the one that works. There is length information about the components, but even if that were absent an attacker could quickly determine where the component boundaries are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR Please just rely on the security of the private key itself rather than relying on anything else; getting that right is hard enough. If you want to increase security, use an external device for storing the key, preferably a HSM or smart card.

---

> I've come to understand that this is the algorithm being encoded to the start. However, I think I'd prefer if third parties had as little info as possible, including what is being used to generate them.

This directly goes against Kerckhoff's principle. If you rely on such things being secret then you've already lost. They'll leak, and given that they are nothing special, it takes about one guess of an attacker.

> How can I remove this info from the header? And what are the consequences? It is really only to be used internally so we can hardcode the missing pieces if necessary.

RSA keys contain multiple components. Of those only the CRT parameters and / or private exponent need to be kept private. But you still need to encode them somehow. The rest just specifies that it is an RSA key, but that's more than obvious from looking at the parameters anyway.

> Any other ideas on why this information is included by default and so hard to code away? RsaPublicKey is final. We should be able to get the public key and private key in their mathematical form if we required to. Prime number and exponent. Why is all this crap included?

You can get the modulus and exponent directly as `BigInteger` values. There's your mathematical form, right? And you can sure reconstruct an `RSAPublicKey` out of it again using `RSAPublicKeySpec` which can be used with `KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")`.

Those are ASN.1 encoded structures. One is called a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure, specified for X.509 (i.e. certificates) and PKCS#1 for the actual public key. The other is a PKCS#8 encoded private key (for which you are viewing the internal structure that could get encrypted), which also relies on PKCS#1 for the actual private key.

Comment: Pfft, just posting an answer to get some quick mental fix.

Comment: I just like to keep information low though, regardless.

Comment: Well, as a security professional of 20 years, I say that you're going straight against best practice. What you do after that is up to you of course...